# Testing NSTimer with location Tracking

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer, cllocationmanager

I have the following code which tracks user location and detect if the user was in one of the specified events in the JSON File by matching the long and the lat of current user location with the long and lat of the today event + when the event starting time is equal to the current iPhone time then perform the following instrucions fire an NSTimer for 5 mins and after 5 mins call this method onTick() where it will calculate the difference between the starting time and the current time afar 5 mins passed, if it is still more than 5 mins, then set this event as attended. The thing is when I tested it on my iPhone it does work but for all the events with time interval more than 5 mins even though I wanted to work for only the present event where the user is at that time !! can anyone plzzz explain for me why is that happening and what could be the solution .. Im really confused ..

Here is my code:

```
    .h file
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Event *currentEvent;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentEventLocation;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *arrivalDate;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *theNewLocation;



  .m file
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

self.currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

if (self.currentEvent) {
    if ([self.arrivalDate timeIntervalSinceNow]<60*3) {
        if ([self.currentEventLocation distanceFromLocation:self.theNewLocation]<100) {
            [self.currentEvent setHasATTENDED:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]];
        }
    }
}

self.currentLocation = self.theNewLocation;

for (Event *event in [self loadTodaysEvents]) {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

    NSString *eventStartTime = event.startingTime;

    // distance
    CLLocationDegrees lat = [event.lat doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees lon = [event.longi doubleValue];
    CLLocation *evLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
    double distance = [evLocation distanceFromLocation:self.theNewLocation];

    // CLOSE !
    if (distance <= 100 && [resultString isEqualToString:eventStartTime]) {
        self.arrivalDate = currentTime;
        self.currentEvent = event;
        self.currentEventLocation = evLocation;
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 180.0
                                                          target: self
                                                        selector: @selector(onTick:)
                                                        userInfo: nil
                                                         repeats: NO];

        NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
  }
}



- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
 {
  [self locationManager:nil didUpdateLocations:@[self.currentLocation]];
 }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

 }
```

Comment: Since the timer is already scheduled, you dont need to ad it to a runloop!

Comment: why do you translate the [NSDate date] to a NSString and back to an NSDate?

Comment: I don't think this line makes sense! Please make sure you really want to check whether the this events start time is the same as the current time!   [resultString isEqualToString:eventStartTime]

Comment: @NilsZiehn so r u saying that the runloop is the one who causing all the events with interval more than 5 mins to be attended ?? so by removing it only the really attended ones will be set as attended ?? I thought it is something wrong in onTick() method !!

Comment: @NilsZiehn NSDate is my fault. I know i should not do that ;p

Comment: Your calculation of minutes is wrong, since when the user is there for exactly one hour, in your calculation its 0 minutes!

Comment: im currently writing you an answer that fixes your initial problem, but I also wanted to point out the other problems ;)

Comment: @NilsZiehn yes I do know that mate, Im only interesting with the minutes part .. but it not that causing the problem !!

Comment: I wanted to point out that if you would just divide by 60 than you are fine! You dont need to remove the hours!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your onTick method you don't test whether you are still at the same event! You just check for any event.

You should do this:

Store which event he is currently attending in the NSTimer and also the events location:

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:event,@"event",evLocation,@"location", nil]
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 180.0
                                                          target: self
                                                        selector: @selector(onTick:)
                                                        userInfo:userInfo
                                                         repeats: NO];
```

Replace the above code with the code where you call the timer.

You also have to store the currentPosition of the iPhone, when the user moves in order to check whether he left the event!

This should also be done in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` call.

For instance use `@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;`

And in the first line of the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` just set `self.currentLocation = newLocation;`

Then in the `onTick` method you check whether you are still close:

```
CLLocation *evLocation = timer.userInfo[@"location"];
Event *event = timer.userInfo[@"event"];

double distance = [evLocation distanceFromLocation:self.currentLocation];

   // CLOSE !
    if (distance <= 100) {
    [event setHasATTENDED:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]];
                 // save
                  NSError *error = nil;
                  if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error])
                     {
                       NSLog(@"Error in saving");
                     }
  }
}
```

You don't need to check the time again, since you already know that the timer fired 5 minutes later!

There is another problem with this approach though!

The user has to keep your iPhone app running during the event, in order for your app to receive the timer callback! You should probably just do everything in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` method, since this should be called even when the app is in the background!

Comment: emm u r right .. but it is necessary if I want to use the NSTimer I have to call a selector .. is there any other way ??

Comment: I meant you should not use NSTimer at all! (Or at least not only )

Comment: Lookt at my other answer for the solution that is not dependent on the NSTimer

Comment: mate Im getting a warning here -->[self locationManager:nil didUpdateToLocation:self.currentLocation fromLocation:self.currentLocation];                                       it says that method is deprecated in iOS 6 >>

Comment: Oh, ya you should use this

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation* currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

Comment: that one is wrong too .. it is saying  >> use of undeclared identifier locationManager !!

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {     there was a * missing in the line, but this doesn't explain your error. you may not have copied my code right...

Comment: well mate I keep getting this error -> use of undeclared identiefier (locationManager) whenever I do it in ur way                               - (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer{

    (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {CLLocation currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
     
}

Comment: I am sorry. I thought you had a better understanding what objective-c code and the actual delegate methods look like. I updated the other answer to the changes you need to do. Please look at the section marked with 'UPDATED CODE:'. You need to copy paste this INSTEAD of your original code!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that should work also when the app is in the background! You have to keep the location manager updating the location, so you know when the user moves and the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` keeps being called!

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Event* currentEvent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* currentEventLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* arrivalDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* currentLocation;



- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
            fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if (self.currentEvent) {
        if ([self.arrivalDate timeIntervalSinceNow]<60*5) {
            if ([self.currentEventLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation]<100) {
                [self.currentEvent setHasATTENDED:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]];
            }
        }
    }
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    for (Event *event in [self loadTodaysEvents]) {

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

        NSString *eventStartTime = event.startingTime;

        // distance
        CLLocationDegrees lat = [event.lat doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees lon = [event.longi doubleValue];
        CLLocation *evLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
        double distance = [evLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];

        // CLOSE !
        if (distance <= 100 && [resultString isEqualToString:eventStartTime]) {
            self.arrivalDate = currentTime;
            self.currentEvent = event;
            self.currentEventLocation = evLocation;
            NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 300.0
                                                              target: self
                                                            selector: @selector(onTick:)
                                                            userInfo: nil
                                                             repeats: NO];

            NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
            [runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        }
    } 
}

- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self locationManager:nil didUpdateToLocation:self.currentLocation fromLocation:self.currentLocation];
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Event* currentEvent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* currentEventLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* arrivalDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* currentLocation;



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager )manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations { 
    CLLocation currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    if (self.currentEvent) {
        if ([self.arrivalDate timeIntervalSinceNow]<60*5) {
            if ([self.currentEventLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation]<100) {
                [self.currentEvent setHasATTENDED:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]];
            }
        }
    }
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    for (Event *event in [self loadTodaysEvents]) {

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

        NSString *eventStartTime = event.startingTime;

        // distance
        CLLocationDegrees lat = [event.lat doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees lon = [event.longi doubleValue];
        CLLocation *evLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
        double distance = [evLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];

        // CLOSE !
        if (distance <= 100 && [resultString isEqualToString:eventStartTime]) {
            self.arrivalDate = currentTime;
            self.currentEvent = event;
            self.currentEventLocation = evLocation;
            NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 300.0
                                                              target: self
                                                            selector: @selector(onTick:)
                                                            userInfo: nil
                                                             repeats: NO];

            NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
            [runner addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        }
    } 
}

- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self locationManager:nil didUpdateLocations:@[self.currentLocation]];        
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tested ur code with my iPhone device after performing few modifications since the above code gave me some warnings, anyway it didn't work, I went to a specified location at that specific time so that I could see if that event was marked as attended but unfortunately nothing really appeared .. do u have any clue why that could happened ??                                    PS, Plzz check my updated code above in the question >>